# Add constant header to flat-file schema in BizTalk

Tags: xsd, biztalk, flat-file

I have **XML** schema with some data. I need to convert this schema to **Flat-File** AND add the **constant header**, which is given separately as a string.

I have 2 possible solutions:

1. Since header values are fixed and happen only once, I will create a separate record for header.
   In this case I will have 2 records level. 1. HeaderTitles and 2. Records. So I use the HeaderTitle record as a filter.
2. We can create 2 schemas:

   (1) Header - This will have one string element type, "Name Age Country". (This is the column header)

   (2) Body - This will be the actual data records. This will have 3 elements, the name, age & the country as repeating records.

   In the pipeline assembler, there is a property where we can decide whether we want to include the header info or not in the final message. We can just disable this.

Can I do this in some other way?

Comment: The constant header is a constant value really or is it variable depending on the origin XML? Anyway, not sure what you need to create two schemas (understanding two .xsd files) The first solution that you propose seems ok.

Comment: Or you receiving or sending the flat file?  If you are sending you need an assembler rather than a disassembler

Comment: @XurxoGarcia Yes, it is a really const value, which is given in advance.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes, I have been mistaken. I am sending file, so I need to configure flat-file assembler.

Comment: Your first option of having a header record in the schema that you populate with same fixed values would be the be approach I would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Option 1 where you have the header in the Flat File schema and you either have default values specified in the schema or set them in the map would be the best and easiest in in my opinion the correct approach.

The only time I would use option 2 is if you had the flat file incoming and needed to disassemble it and actually needed to debatch the record lines into separate messages, which you would do be defining the Body record as occurs 1.